# Use the Google Analytics Script in NUXT project

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I have a website with Nuxt and I want to put the Google Analytics Script on it.

I have downloaded the vue-gtag module

```
yarn add vue-gtag
```

I have created a file in plugins/gtag.js with the code

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueGtag from 'vue-gtag';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
   Vue.use (VueGtag, {
       config: {id: 'UA-XXXXXX-1'},
       appName: 'Archery', 
  });
}
```

And I call it from nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [{
    src: './plugins/gtag.js', 
    mode: 'client'
}]
```

Compiling it with y*arn generate* gives no error, but no code is created in any file either.

Has anyone used gtag on Nuxt and can it help me?

Thanks

Comment: Tried with `'@/plugins...'`? Also, since you defined it as client plugin, it will probably only run when executed on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: here is a detailed post on how to configure it >> https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag/issues/87#issuecomment-594133548

---

If you're using Nuxt, you should rather use the `@nuxtjs/google-analytics` plug-in directly: https://google-analytics.nuxtjs.org/setup/#installation

It will handle some edge cases related to SSR for you and is on top of that, super easy to configure.